# "Cannot connect (null)::newConnection() to myserver::onNewConnection()" - newConnection signal not called

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, server, client

I tried to run simple client-server app in QT. Problem is with "connect" on server side - newConnection slot isn't executed and exception appears (like in title).

***************myserver.cpp***********

```
#include "myserver.h"

myserver::myserver(){}
myserver::~myserver(){}

void myserver::startServer()
{
    qDebug()<<"Starting startServer()";
    tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);
    if (this->listen(QHostAddress::Any,1000))
    {
        qDebug()<<"Listening";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug()<<"Not listening";
    }
}

void myserver::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug()<<"incomingConnection() started";
    socket=new QTcpSocket(this);
    socket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    connect(tcpServer,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(onNewConnection()));
    qDebug()<<socketDescriptor<<"Client connected";
}

void myserver::onNewConnection()
{
    qDebug()<<"onNewConnection() started";
}
```

**********myserver.h**************

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include <QTcpSocket>

class myserver: public QTcpServer
{
     Q_OBJECT

public:
    myserver();
    ~myserver();
    QTcpSocket* socket;
    QTcpServer *tcpServer=nullptr;

public slots:
    void startServer();
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);
    void onNewConnection();
};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

***********testClient.cpp**************

```
#include "myclient.h"
#include "ui_myclient.h"

myclient::myclient(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::myclient)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    socket=new QTcpSocket(this);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(connected()),this,SLOT(socketMap()));
}

myclient::~myclient()
{
    delete ui;
}

void myclient::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    socket->connectToHost("127.0.0.1",1000);
    if(socket->isOpen())
    {
        qDebug()<<"Connected!";
    }
    else {
        qDebug()<<"Not connected";
    }
}

void myclient::socketMap()
{
    qDebug()<<"socketMap() started";
}
```

I expected onNewConnection() being called when client connects. Also I have checked client side and connection is confirmed.

This is console output on server:

```
Starting startServer()
Listening
incomingConnection() started
948 Client connected
```

Comment: Where do you assign `tcpServer` with an actual object?

Comment: Oh yes, i have edited the server cpp code. Now i dont have an exception, but still slot aint firing. I also edited the output

Comment: I don't see your problem, can you clarify a bit more?

Comment: In the first post I forgot to put object `tcpServer = new QTcpServer(this);`
After putting that, it runs without null exception but still doesn't fire OnNewConnection()

Comment: Your class `myserver` both inherits from `QTcpServer` *and* has a `QTcpServer *` member?  That doesn't look right.

Comment: I see. How do you think that should be done?

Comment: Edit: It works as expected when I added this line `connect(this,SIGNAL(newConnection()),this,SLOT(onNewConnection()));` and I didn't need any QTcpServer  members since my "server" class already inherited from it. Thanks everyone